# Ruby on Rails Performance - update row or check first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model Product that has attribute description and code which is an index.

I would like to alter the product in code based on a CSV file.

What is faster?

```
@p = Product.find_by_code(row[:code])
if @p.description != row[:desc]
   @p.update_attribute(:description, row[:desc])
```

or

```
@p = Product.find_by_code(row[:code])
@p.update_attribute(:description, row[:desc])
```

Let's consider all cases, such as descriptions are equal and not equal at all.

How is = comparison implemented for strings and texts?

Comment: _"What is faster?"_ – measure it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ruby [Benchmark](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) module and directly measure that !

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('sort!') do
    @p = Product.find_by(code: row[:code])
    if @p.description != row[:desc]
      @p.description = row[:desc]
      p.save
    end
  end

  x.report('sort')  do
    @p = Product.find_by(code: row[:code])
    @p.description = row[:desc]
    p.save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails is clever enough to know whether an attribute has actually changed, and so won't roundtrip to the database to update a field when it hasn't changed. You can see this on the Rails console (`rails c`) if you run your `update_attribute` code with the same value, and then with a changed value - you'll only see the SQL log output when it's changed.

If you use `update_attributes` instead (which takes a hash of attributes to change) and there is nothing to update, you'll see it does begin and end a transaction with the database, albeit with no commands within it.

Hope that helps!